# gcloud config set project is not working- at least not for the gcloud projects command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

This makes me want to smash my face into my computer screen:

```
>gcloud config set project mydom-dev
Updated property [core/project].

>gcloud config list core/project
[core]
project = mydom-dev
Your active configuration is: [default]

>gcloud projects get-iam-policy mydom-dev
API [cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com] not enabled on project
[mydom-prod]. Would you like to enable and retry?  (Y/n)?
```

WHY mydom-prod? I set to point to my dev project, confirmed its pointing to my dev project but I run this command and its looking at my prod project?

EDIT: when I look at my entire config I see I have an account set (dont recall ever setting this)

```
>gcloud config list
[core]
account = someuser@mydom-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = mydom-dev

Your active configuration is: [default]
```

How do I unset a config? Remove that service account setting and use my user account?

Comment: Do you have any other config settings set or do you have the CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT environment variable set?

Comment: Setting CLOUDSDK_CORE_PROJECT makes no difference either, how do I see what other configs I would have set? I have no other google environment vars set

Comment: that's a service account. If you are running your command within a GCP instance, that field will be populated by the service account of that resource. You can also use "gcloud auth login" to login as yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gcloud config unset account`:

```
$ gcloud config -h
Usage: gcloud config [optional flags] <group | command>
  group may be           configurations
  command may be         get-value | list | set | unset
$ gcloud config get-value account
my_account@my_domain.com
$ gcloud config unset account
Unset property [core/account].
$ gcloud config get-value account
(unset)
$
```

Comment: You don't necessarily want to remove that service account though, if this is a one time command, it's better to just login with your user account and temporarily override the service account